# How to convert an Object to Array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Noob here, Can anyone please help me convert this Object which I am receiving in API Call to an array as mentioned below, also this Object will be dynamic i.e. record length can change. Thanks in advance.

```
myObject = {
  "records": [{
      "id": "recDBqsW7C3Dk3HMd",
      "fields": {
        "Latitude": "24.898907",
        "Longitude": "67.117303",
        "CustomerName": "Asad"
      },
      "createdTime": "2020-10-07T04:43:31.000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "recGlfTbUcEvP46Lf",
      "fields": {
        "Latitude": "24.907641",
        "Longitude": "67.1088035",
        "CustomerName": "Umar"
      },
      "createdTime": "2020-10-07T04:44:11.000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "recfsQsoznDyWPDe8",
      "fields": {
        "Latitude": "24.911112",
        "Longitude": "67.105117",
        "CustomerName": "Ali"
      },
      "createdTime": "2020-10-06T09:11:05.000Z"
    }
  ]
};
```

To something like:

```
myArray = [{
    "lat": 24.898907,
    "lon": 67.117303,
    "name": "Asad"
  },
  {
    "lat": 24.907641,
    "lon": 67.1088035,
    "name": "Umar"
  },
  {
    "lat": 24.911112,
    "lon": 67.105117,
    "name": "Ali"
  }
]
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using `Array.prototype.map` function.

```js
const input = {
  "records": [{
      "id": "recDBqsW7C3Dk3HMd",
      "fields": {
        "Latitude": "24.898907",
        "Longitude": "67.117303",
        "CustomerName": "Asad"
      },
      "createdTime": "2020-10-07T04:43:31.000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "recGlfTbUcEvP46Lf",
      "fields": {
        "Latitude": "24.907641",
        "Longitude": "67.1088035",
        "CustomerName": "Umar"
      },
      "createdTime": "2020-10-07T04:44:11.000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "recfsQsoznDyWPDe8",
      "fields": {
        "Latitude": "24.911112",
        "Longitude": "67.105117",
        "CustomerName": "Ali"
      },
      "createdTime": "2020-10-06T09:11:05.000Z"
    }
  ]
};

const output = input.records.map(({ fields }) => ({
  lat: fields.Latitude,
  lan: fields.Longitude,
  name: fields.CustomerName
}));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: This works actually, however, our inhouse platform does not support map function. is there any other way to do this?

Comment: You need to loop using `for` and add one by one manually then. like this. `const output = [];
for (let i = 0; i < input.records.length; i ++) {
  output.push({
    lat: input.records[i].fields.Latitude,
    lan: input.records[i].fields.Longitude,
    name: input.records[i].fields.CustomerName
  });
}
console.log(output);`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop if the map function is not supported by your platform.

```js
const input = {
  "records": [{
      "id": "recDBqsW7C3Dk3HMd",
      "fields": {
        "Latitude": "24.898907",
        "Longitude": "67.117303",
        "CustomerName": "Asad"
      },
      "createdTime": "2020-10-07T04:43:31.000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "recGlfTbUcEvP46Lf",
      "fields": {
        "Latitude": "24.907641",
        "Longitude": "67.1088035",
        "CustomerName": "Umar"
      },
      "createdTime": "2020-10-07T04:44:11.000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "recfsQsoznDyWPDe8",
      "fields": {
        "Latitude": "24.911112",
        "Longitude": "67.105117",
        "CustomerName": "Ali"
      },
      "createdTime": "2020-10-06T09:11:05.000Z"
    }
  ]
};

const output = [];

for(let record of input.records){
    output.push({
        lat: record.fields.Latitude,
        lan: record.fields.Longitude,
        name: record.fields.CustomerName
    })
}

console.log(output);
```